# Delete character in FileName during SaveAs

Tags: vba, ms-word

This code specifies the name with which to save Word documents.

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=MyString & Mystring2 & MyString3 & MyString4
```

I am trying to remove special characters from a value I've added to the file name.

It works before the final step of removing special characters from MyString4.

MyString4 is `Document.Bookmarks("Index").Range.Text`

I'm trying to declare the whole line as a separate variable.

```
Dim Mystring
MyString4 = Document.Bookmarks("Index").Range.Text
```

and then use the Replace command to get rid of some specific characters.

Unfortunately, it will not let me declare the line as a separate variable. The files get saved without MyString4 at the end.

Comment: It’s not completely clear what the problem with your code is, but trying to put both the declaration and the assignment on the same line is going to create problems. Further, as it stands, you have Dim Mystring, when the variable you need is MyString4. I suggest you put “Dim MyString4 As String” (without the quotation marks)  on a separate line (you may find other declarations at the top of the module,Sub or Function, then the assignment (MyString4 = etc.) on a separate line.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to replace

```
MyString & Mystring2 & MyString3 & MyString4
```

with a call to a function that does the necessary replacments

```
SafeFileName(MyString & Mystring2 & MyString3 & MyString4)
```

Using

```
Public Function SafeFileName(ByVal ipFileName as String) as String

    ' Do as many replaces as you need
    ipFileName=Replace(ipFileNAme, <your find text 1>, <your replace text>
    ipFileName=Replace(ipFileNAme, <your find text 2>, <your replace text>
    ipFileName=Replace(ipFileNAme, <your find text 3>, <your replace text>
    SafeFileName = ipFilename

End Function
```

You can be smarter by using a regexp in your function but this might be a job for another day.

Comment: Instead of copy-pasting that line a bunch, couldn't you just do like `while instr(ipFileName, <your find text>) <> 0`? Just curious.

Comment: @HaydenMoss. You clearly don't understand what is being done in the function.  To make things clearer I've amended the answer slightly.

Comment: wow yeah I should probably do more than a cursory glance before commenting, haha my bad

Comment: @HaydenMoss No Worries, the answer is better as a consequence of your comment.

Comment: If you had a lot of replaces to do, it may be tidier to use an array and a loop rather than listing all of the replacements. Unless you are paid per line of code!!!

Comment: I was trying to keep things simple for the OP.  You will note he was struggling with assigning a value to a string.  In practise I'd use a regexp to remove non legal windows  filename characters in a single operation.

Answer (score 0):

For example, the following replaces illegal filename characters with underscores:

```
Dim i As Long: Const StrExcl As String = """*./\:?|"
StrName = MyString & Mystring2 & MyString3 & MyString4
For i = 1 To Len(StrExcl)
  StrName = Replace(StrName, Mid(StrExcl, i, 1), "_")
Next
StrName = Trim(StrName)
ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=StrName & ".docx"
```